# Setting up remote access on command-line ubuntu server

Tags: server, remote-desktop, remote, remote-login

I have an ubuntu server (command-line version of ubuntu). I want to access it from home using putty from outside the facility. I need a step-wise guide to setup remote access on my server. I am using Windows10 on my home computer(PC).

Comment: can you please paste a link to a recommended guide

Comment: Start at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH